# How to make cakedc Users available in the whole application in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

How do i make the cakedc users plugin available in all my application. i tried using some of the variables in the default.ctp layout and i get "undefined index" error message even after loading the user model in the appController.php file. please how do i make the plugin available through out the application.
here is what i have tried (AppController.php):

```
class AppController extends Controller {

   public function beforeFilter(){
  return $this->set('user', $this->getuser());

     }  

   function getuser(){
   if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')){
   $this->loadModel('User');
  $user = $this->User->find('first',array(
         'conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')),'fields'=>array('id'))
  );
  if (!$user || empty($user)) return false;
     return $user;
   }
return false;
 }
}
```

and how do i output it in the view, that is default.ctp?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `loadModel()` you need to include the plugin name using Cake's plugin syntax (*i.e.* `pluginName.modelName`):-

```
$this->loadModel('Users.User');
```

Otherwise it will look for the User model in your app not the plugin.